# LocalStorage variable not persisting in Chromium Kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, chromium, kiosk

I have a web app that's been working fine using localStorage as a way to persist data. Just recently, maybe due to an update perhaps?, Chromium on Raspbian has decided that localStorage is not a thing it wants to do anymore. I don't really know how else to persist data. I only need to store the value of two variables. I am using the typical syntax of

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
```

When I power off the machine, the values are gone. I am using this on a live project and I'm in desperate need of a way to get this data to persist but I don't know how else to do it. SessionStorage doesn't persist through shut downs. Can anyone help? For reference, the chromium version is 65.0.3325.181

```
function grow(){
      currentZoom += 1;
      $("#content").css('font-size', currentZoom + 'px');
      $("#content").css('height', currentZoom + 'px');
      localStorage.setItem("storeSize", currentZoom);
      console.log("grow triggered");
  }


  function shrink(){
     currentZoom -= 1;
     $("#content").css('font-size', currentZoom + 'px');
     $("#content").css('height', currentZoom + 'px');
     localStorage.setItem("storeSize", currentZoom);
     console.log("shrink triggered");
  }

   function mirror(){
       $("testDisplay").addClass("mirror");
       localStorage.setItem("mirror", 1);
   }
```

Comment: You should look into how powering down the machine effects the storage. Does this flush your chrome data somehow? It seems it may be related to the shutdown action if this is the only time it's happening. You can read about where your data is stored here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

Comment: i would think that, except that 4 weeks ago it was working fine. the pi stays on most of the time. I had a co-worker shut it down a few days ago and we noticed the data had not persisted. which just meant that we had to recalibrate it how we needed. It wasn't a problem at my local office but i have these spread out and i can't get to all of them.

Comment: There hasn't been any changes in chrome that would effect this specifically. The only way based on documentation that your data can be cleared is if it's done manually. I think even data persists over browser updates. I think it would invalidate itself if the origin changed  ( if you changed your url from example.com to example1.com )

Comment: Side note - You could add a secondary solution using cookies that load into storage in case this happens again but be aware cookies do expire. There are plenty of good libraries out there to do this.

Comment: right. the url has stayed the same. and it works in regular chromium. when the pi boots up, there's a start script that runs this web page and auto sets it to kiosk mode. it's a pretty basic app so that's why this is set this way. but anything done in kiosk mode does not persist to regular chromium and vice versa.

Comment: exactly, the expiration of cookies is why local storage was the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that Chromium by default store profile and session data in the temp folder <s>when launched in kiosk mode</s> sometimes, I'm not sure why, this folder is purged on system reboot, at least on Raspbian, other OSes may behave differently. A comment suggested using cookies instead, but that won't work as they go in the temp folder as well.

You can pass a command line argument to Chromium in order to use a different location for profile data, that should solve the problem:

```bsh
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --kiosk --user-data-dir=/myprofilefolder/
```

Remember to make sure that the folder exists, and that the appropriate user has write permission.

Comment: are you sure? i spent a few days looking up new ways to configure my set up and after just basically starting again from scratch and setting up just like i had it the first time on a fresh install of raspbian, it worked with js cookies. I've rebooted several times and it holds my calibrations. Keep in mind, the app was working perfectly until i posted my question here when it randomly just stopped with no warning

Comment: I'm sure that is how it worked on my machine. Maybe Raspbian doesn't always clear /tmp/ on reboot. Try creating a file in /tmp/, reboot, and see if it disappears while the cookies stay?

Comment: i just checked in the /tmp folder. I have a cookie stored on the device called "storeSize". there's no file even remotely named that. should i check this using the raspbian gui as opposed to ssh? is there a hashing system i need to be aware of that changes cookie names? Or has the newest distro of raspbian made changes to where the files are saved?

Comment: Cookies are stored in database files so you can't see the individual cookies directly, if Chromium stores the profile in tmp it is in a hidden folder in tmp with lots of files and subfolders. But now I can't repro by launching from a terminal, so maybe the cause is not kiosk mode.